# SQL Server - Pivot Inserting NULL values, need them skipped

Tags: sql, null, pivot

I'm doing some work to extract some info from a database, which includes using a pivot to get the info in the format we need it in.

The problem is, this pivot is including a heap of NULL values and therefore making some info start quite a few columns away from the first pivoted column.

Code is here:

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE dbo.tempTable
(
    id varchar(100),
    FirstName varchar(100),
    LastName varchar(100),
    code varchar(100),
    rn int
)
END

BEGIN
with base as (
select distinct tblstudent.code as ID, tblstudent.firstname as FirstName, tblstudent.FamilyName as LastName,  tblSubject.code as code

from  tblSubject inner join tblSubjectChoice on tblSubject.id = tblSubjectChoice.subjectid inner join tblStudent on tblSubjectChoice.studentid = tblstudent.id
)

insert into temptable
SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by base.LastName order by base.ID) as rn
FROM base

END

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM tempTable
pivot (min (code) for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20])) as pvt

DROP TABLE tempTable

END
```

(I'm very aware it's probably not the most efficient way to do this, but I'm not asking about that. Our dataset isn't huge)

Most come out fine, for example:

```
11111   John    Smith   8A  8B  8C  8D  8E  8F  8G  8H  8I  8J  8K  8L  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

That's perfect.

However, others come out like:

```
11112   Bob Smith   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8F  8G  8H  8I  8J  8K  8L  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

As you can see, it's not skipping NULL and is inserting all. That's not what we want.

I've tried mucking around with putting in "where IS NOT NULL" is places, but it's still inserting stuff :(

EDIT (MORE INFO):
I've taken out some data as I'm dealing with sensitive data here.

tblSubject: ID(PK) CODE NAME

2ADD5FE0-EDC2-49FA-94C6-00BCDCD059D4    8A  French

tblSubjectChoice is a table which has the PKs of tblsubject and tblstudent. I can't provided specific examples, but I'm only using the columns expressed in the SQL statement.

Basically my data is trying to extract all classes from all students. It does this fine, it's just the pivot is inserting NULL values.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you can edit your question and include data from your actual tables `tblSubject`, `tblSubjectChoice`, etc and then show the desired final result?  It would be much easier to see what you want using that.

Comment: Updated:

I just checked too, with a result that was getting the nulls at the start. If I specifically select and say "where tblstudent.firstname = X and tblstudent.lastname = Y", and thus only pass through one result, the pivot works fine. No nulls are there. 

I can't see any pattern to why it has nulls for every 5-10th tuple?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge idiot :)

The bug was "partition by base.lastname". It just kept going for students with the same last name (but wasn't ordering them rightly? So I couldn't see the pattern). Partitioning by base.id works perfectly.

Thanks for your help, bluefeet :)